# How to Debug Java Application using VIM/GVIM?

Tags: java, debugging, vim, editor

I asked this question previously ([any-good-tutorial-for-moving-from-eclipse-to-vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495268/any-good-tutorial-for-moving-from-eclipse-to-vim))

From the inputs, I started using GVIM instead of Eclipse. I added `ctags` to it and I am able to navigate now comfortably.

The only problem left for me is "Debugging"? I tried searching for some links, and couldn't find a useful one?

If anyone using or familiar with Java Debugging using vim/Gvim, can provide their inputs/ links/tutorials, it would be very helpful.

Comment: VIM is a text editor, it has many cool features but it's not an IDE. From that link to the other question I understand that they are hosting a VIM editor inside of eclipse not the other way around, hosting a debugging session in VIM...

Comment: Ya, I understand that it is an IDE and I am not using the Eclipse VIM plugin. I like VIM stand alone. 

I heard that we can debug CPP, PHP, etc in VI, So, my question is is there any possibility for debugging in Java.

Comment: for e.g: http://xdebug.org/index.php there for PHP debugging.

Comment: Can this get an update?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your best bet seems to be integration of the command line debugger `jdb`, one such solution is [yavdb](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1954), another is [JavaKit](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1154).

Comment: I think the JavaKit sounds helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Eclim now supports a Java debugger. See http://eclim.org/vim/java/debug.html

Answer (score 1):

You may not avoid installing a [standalone debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370072/recomend-a-standalone-java-debugger)

(like an eclipse you will use only for remote debugging your application)

Answer (score 1):

Eclim offers integration between Vim and Eclipse.  It should allow you to use Eclipse's debugger in Vim

Comment: I use eclim and it doesn't have debugging capabilities

Answer (score 1):

## Debugging in Vim:

Meanwhile there is [vimspector](https://github.com/puremourning/vimspector), which is

> A multi language graphical debugger for Vim.

### Debugging Java in Vim:

For using it with Java refer to [this Section](https://github.com/puremourning/vimspector#java).

*Note:* Be aware that it requires one of the following versions:

1. Vim 8.2 Huge build compiled with Python 3.6 or later
2. Neovim 0.4.3 with Python 3.6 or later (experimental)

Answer (score -3):

there is an awesome vim plugin for netbeans called jVi, at http://jvi.sourceforge.net/