# a short HOW TO on ECLIM

Tags: debugging, servlets, perforce, eclim

Hi 
I have a list of How to unanswered. It would be great if anyone can help me in this

1) How to **debug** in eclim

2) How to create **servlets** easily ( with the template included by default)

3) By any chance is there any support for plugins like '**Perforce**'

There are few things like support for junit, getter/setter/construction etc . There should definitely be a good support for the above . Of all things debugging should be there for sure. Unfortunately I am not able to find out how.

Please add more questions and lot more answers. 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. I debug in eclipse. I don't think eclim provides debugging from vim. However, there are solutions. See question [How to Debug Java Application using VIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545056/how-to-debug-java-application-using-vim-gvim).
2. Are you just talking about using eclipse's new file wizard to create servlets? I don't know how you could do that from Vim. But you can use vim's templates. Vim's method of templates are referred to in [vimdoc as skeleton files](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#skeleton). It looks like there are some plugins to provide some defaults: [skeleton](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2291) and [tSkeleton](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1160).
3. When I use perforce, I use this [perforce.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=240) plugin.

Eclim [supports junit](http://eclim.org/vim/java/junit.html). For getter/setter/construction and other code snippets, try [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540).