# Play framework and Sublime Text 2 - Is debugging possible?

Tags: playframework, sublimetext2

I've started using the Play framework and Sublime Text 2. It's a really nice development environment but one thing is missing - debugging capability.

I saw some guides on the net explaining how to set up debugging in ST2 for PHP. So is there any way of debugging Java applications in ST2, and in particular Play applications?

Comment: Not currently, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227530/how-to-debug-java-application-from-sublime-text-editor

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Ensime with Sublime http://flurdy.com/docs/ensime/sublime.html? You might also really enjoy CTags for STS 2 or Goto definition on STS 3.