# Vim - When I run my Java file, the println statements don't seem to be getting executed

Tags: java, vim, javac

I'm using GVim. I created a file caled InsertionSort.java and this is what is inside the file:

```
public class InsertionSort {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

I then opened up terminal and did

```
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

to install javac. Next, I went back to GVim and did:

```
:!javac %
```

to run the current file. When I did this, it said:

```
!javac /Documents/Java/InsertionSort.java
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

and when I press ENTER, it goes back to InsertionSort.java. It doesn't print anything. I looked at this post: [Compiling Java code in Vim more efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411979/compiling-java-code-in-vim-more-efficiently) and the highest rated answer said to add these to my .vimrc file:

```
autocmd Filetype java set makeprg=javac\ %
set errorformat=%A%f:%l:\ %m,%-Z%p^,%-C%.%#
map <F9> :make<Return>:copen<Return>
map <F10> :cprevious<Return>
map <F11> :cnext<Return>
```

After adding the above lines to my .vimrc file, I reopend GVim / InsertionSort.java and pressed F9 and it said:

```
!javac Documents/Java/InsertionSort.java 2>&1| tee /tmp/vcqcE1x/8

:copen

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

and when I pressed ENTER, it opened up a new GVim file called:

```
[Quickfix List] :javac Documents/Java/InsertionSort.java
```

and the file did not have anything in it (It didn't say "Hello World"). How do I make it run the file so that it displays "Hello World"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be mixing up the `java` and `javac` programs. `javac` compiles `*.java` source files into `*.class` bytecode files. `java` takes compiled `*.class` bytecode files and runs them. So if your goal is to compile and run a file called `Example.java`, you'll need to do this:

```
javac Example.java
java Example
```

Answer (score 1):

`javac` is the *compiler,* not the executor. It will compile your source code into a class file which then needs to be run with `java` rather than `javac`.

Answer (score 0):

If your system has jdk you should be able to compile your java file using
    `javac program.java`
When your java file is successfully compiled,JVM converts java file into `.class` file. Now you can run your `.class` file using `java program`