# Display :make compiler output for a Java compiled program

Tags: java, javac, neovim

I am trying to get NeoVim to compile a simple Java program. The program itself has no ideas but I am not able to exactly output the compiled program.

I have this in my config:

```
autocmd Filetype java set makeprg=javac\ %            
set errorformat=%A%f:%l:\ %m,%-Z%p^,%-C%.%#           
map <F9> :make<Return>:copen<Return>                  
map <F10> :cprevious<Return>                          
map <F11> :cnext<Return>
```

I am able to see errors and compile but don't know how to see the output directly in NeoVim. Any way I can do so because I couldn't figure it out nor could find any useful information online.

Comment: Output of what? Of `:make` command or your Java program?

Comment: Of the Java program

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411979/compiling-java-code-in-vim-more-efficiently/14727153.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Neovim you have 2 options:

1. suspend the editor (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>), run your program and then return to editor with `fg` command
2. use build-in terminal

<sup>In Vim you would also have 3rd option: to use `:!`, but in Neovim it doesn't support input yet (see [issue #1496](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/1496))</sup>

If you choose option 2 then you simply use command `:term java %<`

But you would probably want it in a new window (in Neovim `:term` takes over the current one).
In such case you would need to use command: `:new term://java %<`

So in conclusion you would need to add to your `init.nvim` the following:

```
autocmd Filetype java nnoremap <F8> :new term://java %<<CR>
```